# Is there a known API endpoint for Pinterest profile pictures?

Tags: pinterest

It looks like pinterest photos are stored in a very simple manner.  They appear to have addresses of the form:

http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/avatars/*username* _ *timestamp* _ *size*.jpg

- *username* is the pinterest user
- *timestamp* is the unix timestamp when the photo was uploaded
- *size* is the pixel size of the resulting image's width and height (known accepted values are 140 and 30)

Of course, using this link is basically impossible, as I don't know the time of upload.

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you find when you looked through their [developer documentation](http://developers.pinterest.com/)?

Comment: unfortunately, pinterest is full of undocumented features, and their developer docs are practically worthless.  For example, there is absolutely no documentation for their api, despite many little tricks that work, such as https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/boards/highquality/travel/pins/